# Solr that runs on a docker container takes localhost but not the container IP

Tags: centos, docker, localhost, apache-solr

I have used official [CentOS 7 image](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) from Docker Hub and created a container that runs ***Solr 8.4.1*** version. I was able to start and run the Solr without any issue. My concern is, Solr admin UI loads with *localhost* URL (http://localhost:7574/solr/) but not with the assigned IP for the container (http://172.18.0.6:7574/solr/).

*/etc/hosts* file in the container is looks like below.

```
[solr@solrtwo solr-8.4.1]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.6  solrtwo
```

Also I have enable following line in ***solr.in.sh*** as well

```
SOLR_HOST="172.18.0.6"
```

Furthermore, result for the docker inspect for the container is looks like below.

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "87cf51134d0b4bc3068ab8e294f5dc91bfc2db79528064002135beaa6c84b074",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "7574/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "7574"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/87cf51134d0b",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "zone1": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "095f310ec70f"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "c9ab125d4c36228a46447514f0e13867bff50607c6c1e4b726172b5c3393a9fb",
                "EndpointID": "19a143b947bab68fe058e87f130bd1dd2e3b89b32c27d826c9ee4b3b55d30474",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.6",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
```

**I want to load Solr admin UI with container IP address instead of localhost. How can I do that?**